# Issues while running spark submit

Tags: apache-spark

ENV Detail:

Dataproc cluster
edge node  - createdc using master node image of the dataproc cluster.
Trying to to spark-submit:
Ex: spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout=10 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=15 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1 --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 4 --name  --class  --properties-file /data/apps/XXXXX_config/config-filename --jars /data/apps/<custom-jar.jar>

Getting Error:

does not existread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:634)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:860)

excuting saprksubmit via shell script - shell script is creating spark-submit and manually works fine without any issues.
when run via shell script its questions of path and jar file.

Any suggestion
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting:

`<file> does not exist at read "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file: at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:634) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:860)`

is due to the file that you're trying to access is not able to be found on the node where the spark code is being executed. Any file that should be accessible  should be passed in using the --files flag. This will distribute that file to each worker node.